# Highlighting by context

Tags: highlighting, thing-at-point

Are there tools for highlighting by context?  When writing my configuration code, I constantly get into the difficulty of figuring out where in the different block of code I am modifying.  Looking for any modes that could highlight the section around the cursor that forms part of a syntactic structure.  For instance, highlight the `pcase` section when modifying that section.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what you mean by "highlighting".

If you mean select as the active region (which also lets `C-x C-x` take you to its start/end), then this can help:

If you use library [`thing-cmds.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ThingAtPointCommands) ([code](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/thing-cmds.el)) then you can select lists that enclose point using command `select-enclosing-list-backward` (bound to `C-M-B` if you use command `thgcmd-bind-keys`).

Repeating the command selects wider and wider enclosing lists.  E.g., you're somewhere inside a `pcase` sexp.  You repeat `C-M-B` till it selects the `pcase` sexp.

---

If you mean highlight so the highlighting (face) remains, then first use `C-M-B` as above, then use a highlighting command to highlight the region.  If you use library [`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([code](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)) then you can use command `hlt-highlight-region` to do that.  It's bound by default to `C-x X h x`. (All keys defined by the library are on keymap `hlt-map`, which is bound by default to prefix key `C-x X`.)

Comment: Not highlighting that remains, but is done near the cursor (highlighting nearby context), which gets deactivated and focused somewhere else as the cursor is moved through the code.  For elisp I have found `highlight-sexp`.

Comment: 1. Put all info to specify your question into the question. Don't flesh out your question in comments. 2. Don't change/evolve the question, especially after there are answers to the it as originally posed. Instead, pose a new question.

Comment: If you want to always have a sexp at point highlighted (till you turn off the mode), then maybe that's what you want. If you instead want to highlight a sexp at point on demand (and repeat to widen the sexp at point that's used) then what I described might be what you want.

Comment: That's an interesting though, will try it.

Comment: @Dilna if this answered your question, please mark it as an answer for future users of the site. If your solution required modifications from this, please add your own answer to the question, then mark it as an answer for future users of the site. Thank you.